# JS counting repeat occurrences

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

I need to find if the string inside td.aws appears more than 3 times, and if it does, put that string into a new list.

I have a table like so:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="1" class="aws_data">
<tbody><tr bgcolor="#ECECEC"><th>URL (1,908)</th></tr>
<tr><td class="aws">/images/bullet3.png</td></tr>
<tr><td class="aws">/pdf-signing-tool/ErrorCode.properties</td></tr>
<tr><td class="aws">/pdf-signing-tool/Display.properties</td></tr>
<tr><td class="aws">/evcert.cfm</td></tr>
<tr><td class="aws">/evcert.cfm</td></tr>
<tr><td class="aws">/evcert.cfm</td></tr>
<tr><td class="aws">/evcert.cfm</td></tr>
<tr><td class="aws">/repository/03</td></tr>
<tr><td class="aws">/repository/0</td></tr>
etc

<div id="problems"></div>
```

So far I have:

```
$('.aws').each(function(){
var temp = $(this).text();
var count = temp.match('/'+temp+'/g');  

if (count.length > 3)
{
    thisString = $(this).text();
    $('#problems').append(thisString)
}

});
```

Can anyone help , at the moment I'm just getting JS error "count is null"

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qT6Nz/)

Comment: Regexes are literals of the form `/regex/mods`, not strings. To use a string as a regex, run it through `new RegExp` (but note that the slashes are not needed and the modifiers are the second parameter).

Comment: Why would the expected count be more than 3 in the example you've given?

Comment: Could you give a better example? If you take the whole text of an element, then the text will only occur once inside inside the element. The code you tried does not make a lot of sense to me. You are just testing whether the string matches itself, which should always be the case but the result will always be an array of length one.

Comment: Sorry, the example was bad. I've added one that appears three times now. I'm trying to basically see if there are duplicates. So "evcert.cfm" now appears three times

Comment: @Barney Edited that to make it four times, because the code only triggers *after* three occurrences :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qT6Nz/3/)

```
//store the counts for each "text" occurrence in a hash table
var countHash = {}; 

//iterate over your tds
$('.aws').each(function(){

    //pull of the text
    var temp = $(this).text();

    //has it already been added to the list? 
    //see: 'countHash[temp] = false;' below.
    if(countHash[temp] === false){return;}

    //increment the occurrence count
    //or set to 1 if this is the first occurrence.
    countHash[temp] = (countHash[temp] || 0) + 1; 

    //have more than three been found?
    if (countHash[temp] > 3)
    {
        //add to your list
        $('#problems').append(temp);

        //ignore future occurrences
        countHash[temp] = false; 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression like that should be created with `new RegExp()`, as mentioned in the comments. Besides that, using the inner text of each table cell may lead to an invalid regular expression if things like brackets and question marks are used. So in this case I would advice against that.

You can do frequency counting like this while you iterate over each `td.aws`:

```
var frequencies = {};

$('td.aws').each(function() {
    var key = $(this).text(),
    freq = frequencies[key] || 0;

    // increase the frequency and check if it goes above 3
    if (++freq > 3) {
        $('#problems').append(key);
        freq = -Infinity;
    }

    frequencies[key] = freq;
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qT6Nz/)

The object `frequencies` keeps the frequency of each term in its properties; once it reaches a certain number it will do whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = {};
$(".aws").each(function(i,v) {
    var temp = $(v).text();
    var current = count[temp];
    if (!current) {
        current = 0;
    }
    current++;
    count[temp] = current;
    if (current > 3) {
       $("#problems").append("<p>"+temp+"</p>");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if you want to remove the item that occurs three times from the old list so I didn't add that

Comment: This will append an item multiple times (once for every time its frequency goes above 3).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here: `'/'+temp+'/g'` You can't use variables in a regular expression literal. You'll have to build the regular expression as a string:

```
var tempRegex = new RegExp(temp, 'g');
var count = temp.match(tempRegex);
```

You appear to have a larger logical problem in your code. Right now you are building a regular expression to see if the text matches itself, which is always will. I think you're trying to search through all the TDs to determine if there is duplicates. Try this approach instead:

```
var items = [];

$('.aws').each(function(){
    var currentText = $(this).text();
    var duplicate = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].text === currentText) {
            items[i].count++;

            if (items[i].count > 2) {
                console.log('found more than 2 of ' + currentText);
                $('#problems').append(currentText)
            }

            duplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!duplicate) {
        items.push({ text: currentText, count: 1});
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qT6Nz/2/

Comment: This will append the duplicate multiple times (once for every time it goes above 2 times). Also, it would be better to use an object's properties to implement frequency counting.

Comment: @Jack and what happens when the text contains a character that is not allowed in an object property identifier?

Comment: Well, properties can always be accessed with the `[]` syntax, so using any string should work just as well.